# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt

Tags: c++, boost

I recently upgraded from boost 1.40 to 1.45 by removing the previous boost directory completely, downloading the 1.45 sources and rebuilding the libraries I wanted. I then installed the libs using bjam install.

Nothing else has changed on my machine, yet, now when I am building my C++ program, I get the following link error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
```

I searched and the file really does not exist. It seems that the mt libraries are no longer part of the library - or am I missing something?

How may I resolve this?

Comment: Can you build with the non-multithreaded library (just `boost_system`)?

Comment: Try `rpm -ql boost-devel | grep libboost` to see what .so you've got.

Comment: @chris/Hans: yes I successfully built and installed the following boost libs: filesystem, serialisation, regex, program_options.

Comment: @skyeagle you'll need to build and install `boost_system` as well if you intended to link against it. It would help if you indicate how you upgraded your system. Did you install from an RPM or build it from source using bjam?

Comment: @sam: I 'upgraded' by removing the previous boost directory completely, downloaded the 1.45 sources and rebuilt the libraries I wanted. I then installed the libs using bjam install

Comment: @Maxim: I am running on Ubuntu (no rpm)

Comment: @skyeagle are you sure you built the `system` library? What arguments did you provide to `bootstrap.sh` and `bjam`?

Comment: @sam: Yes, I built the system. I run the following commands: ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem,iostreams,program_options,regex,serialization,system --prefix=/usr/local/  and then ./bjam install

Comment: @skyeagle do you see a `libboost_system.so` or `libboost_system-mt.so` in `/usr/local/lib`?

Answer (score 22):

Well, I solved this error on ubuntu 12.04 (x86_64) by the good old scattergun approach

Installing openvrml with the error "cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt" after make.

libboost-all-dev. installs 54 different packages. One of 'em must've done the trick, runs fine.

Comment: Ha!  I was avoiding installing that package until I saw this post.  Worked for me

Answer (score 7):

This version probably doesn't bring multi-threading enabled by default.

Try passing `-lboost_system` instead of `-lboost_system-mt`

**Edit:**

Also it's good to check if the new libs are really inside `/usr/local/lib`. You should look for **/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so** since you did not requested the libs to be built with multi-threading. If the file is there, then your **$PATH** (environment variable) could be missing `/usr/local/lib`, and you should update the compilation command so the compiler knows where to find them:

`-L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system-mt`

Comment: great answer - in couple cases I had this worked w/o issues (depends on the specifics I guess)

Answer (score 5):

I had a strange encounter with this, too. My solution was a bid odd - but since it worked for me and I didn't read about it anywhere else, here it is.
In my case *lboost_python3* was missing.

Hence, i loaded all 54 packages like @Kilgore Trout suggested:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Unfortunately, when i looked into the `/usr/lib` - folder only certain packages were available there. However, when I searched `/usr/lib` I got more results - the missing files were all in the `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` - folder.

I simply copy-pasted all *libboost*-related files into the `/usr/lib`-folder et voilà - the next time I tried to build anything with the *lboost_python3.so* , everything worked.

It seems some paths got mixed up or something like this.
Hope this helps you or somebody else.

Answer (score 2):

I have saucy:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
libboost-system1.49-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
```

thus, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.49-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Are your sure the `/usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so` sym-link point to the right file:

```
$ realpath /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
```

Otherwise you have to install the project or use yours distribution package management. For Debian/Ubuntu it would be `apt-get install libboost-system1.45-dev` -- but this package does not exists while writing this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this thanks to [@KilgoreTrout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10418569/277826)'s and  [@user3191035](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21096600/277826), so here's my notes: I'm on Ubuntu Natty 11.04; my usual state was:

```
$ dpkg -S libboost_filesystem
libboost-filesystem1.42.0: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0
```

Then I installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev # ton of packages
```

... and after that, I get this:

```
$ dpkg -S libboost_filesystem
libboost-filesystem1.42-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a
libboost-filesystem1.42.0: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0
libboost-filesystem1.42-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so
libboost-filesystem1.42-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so
libboost-filesystem1.42-dev: /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.a
```

So, that is where the `libboost_filesystem-mt.so` is in this OS...

Answer (score 1):

change libboost_thread-mt to libboost_thread, first find the address of libboost_thread.so and libboost_thread.a then make softlinks to these files in the same address, so it should be

```
ln -s /...libboostSourceFiles.../libboost_thread.so /..RequestTOmtFiles.../libboost_thread-mt.so
```

it works for other libboost -mt files too, like serialization , iostreams, programoptions