# makefile.unix:188: obj/magirpc.o Error 1 when compiling

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors

When I was compiling the [magi wallet](https://github.com/m-pays/magi) (Using [this](https://raspi2miner.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/build-your-magicoin-xmg-wallet/) guide) I came across these errors when compiling it. After searching around on Bing and Google I seem to have found no solution for this and the only mention of this at all is in the [makefile](https://github.com/m-pays/magi/blob/master/src/makefile.unix) of the actual project. I have found nothing on how to solve this problem and the GitHub repo hasn't been updated in about 3 years and no one is answering the questions there. Can anyone help me? (All the errors are listed below and they are ordered in the time they appeared)

```
magirpc.cpp: At global scope:
magirpc.cpp:668:102: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
static void RPCAcceptHandler(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:668:104: error: template argument 1 is invalid
static void RPCAcceptHandler(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:678:95: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
static void RPCListen(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:678:97: error: template argument 1 is invalid
static void RPCListen(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:683:91: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
 AcceptedConnectionImpl<Protocol>* conn = new AcceptedConnectionImpl<Protocol>(acceptor->get_io_service(), context, fUseSSL);

magirpc.cpp:685:13: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
 acceptor->async_accept(

magirpc.cpp:700:102: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
static void RPCAcceptHandler(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:700:104: error: template argument 1 is invalid
static void RPCAcceptHandler(boost::shared_ptr< basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, SocketAcceptorService> > acceptor,

magirpc.cpp:710:17: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
  && acceptor->is_open())

magirpc.cpp:711:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘RPCListen(int&, boost::asio::ssl::context&, const bool&)’
     RPCListen(acceptor, context, fUseSSL);

magirpc.cpp:775:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
 ssl::context context(io_service, ssl::context::sslv23);

magirpc.cpp:791:41: error: ‘class boost::asio::ssl::context’ has no member named ‘impl’
     SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(context.impl(), strCiphers.c_str());

magirpc.cpp:816:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘RPCListen(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&, boost::asio::ssl::context&, const bool&)’
     RPCListen(acceptor, context, fUseSSL);

magirpc.cpp:842:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘RPCListen(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >&, boost::asio::ssl::context&, const bool&)’
         RPCListen(acceptor, context, fUseSSL);

magirpc.cpp:1085:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::ssl::context::context(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method)’
 ssl::context context(io_service, ssl::context::sslv23);

make: *** [makefile.unix:188: obj/magirpc.o] Error 1
```

Note: For the full log of the build please click [here](https://pastebin.com/XG59GS1E).

Thanks,

swanserquack

Comment: That is not the error.  That's just a message from make telling you that your compile failed.  This error likely has nothing to do with make or the makefile but it's impossible to know from this information.  You have to look earlier in the output and find the compiler error (when debugging build issues always find the **first** failure, not the last one).  For any help at all we'd need to see the compile line that make invoked and the errors the compiler gave (at least the first batch, if there are a lot).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info, using proper formatting rather than putting it into a comment.  It's hard to understand content in comments where it can't be formatted.  Also, please show the compiler invocation before you got this error.  It looks to me like perhaps you have a different version of Boost, or something.

Comment: Hello @MadScientist, I have now updated the post with some more info and the errors which showed up. If you need more info then just let me know. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above it looks to me like this code wants a different version of Boost than the one you're using.  The version of boost you're using wants one argument to the template for `basic_socket_acceptor` and this code is trying to pass two arguments.

Looking at the Boost documentation I can see that the current latest version does want two arguments; see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor.html  And I can see that up to version 1.69 wanted one argument one-argument version; see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor.html

It appears that this signature was changed in Boost 1.70.

So it seems the version of Boost you're trying to compile with is too old and this set of code wants you to use a newer version, so you'll need to upgrade your Boost.

Comment: Hey @MadScientist, I have managed to install a new version of boost however I get [this](https://pastebin.com/9wKPspfZ) error and after searching for a bit I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596492/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lboost-system-mt) post showing to try to install everything. When trying to install libboost1.55-all-dev(Which seems to work) I get [this](https://pastebin.com/Fswn8BiU) error and most of the packages needed are reliant on libboost-date-time1.55 and when I try to install that I get [this](https://pastebin.com/EbprYTBC) error. Can you help me?

Comment: Not really.  It looks like there's no valid version of that boost library available as a package for your operating system (you didn't specify which distribution you're using).  If you need it you'll have to build it yourself, it appears.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I don't even see that version of libboost available (the oldest I have is 1.67).